# How to ask user for keys in dictionary, and if it is in dictionary, display the values

Tags: python

how to display key(integers)in dictionary when user enters key(integers)

```
string = input("Please enter a name> ")
def enumerate_string(string):
  s = {}
  for i,letter in enumerate(string):
     s[i] = letter
x = enumerate_string(string)
string2 = input("enter several integers separated by a comma ")
string3 = string2.split(',')
if string3 in set(x):
   print(x[string3])
```

Comment: if dictionary is {0:'c',1:'s',2:'c',3:'1',4:'2',5:'0'}
and the user enters === 0,1,2 for key(integers)
it should display == 'c','s','c'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am updating part of your code:

```
string2 = input("enter several integers separated by a comma ") # 0,1,2
string3 = string2.split(',') # string3 is a list of numbers but as strings
# ['0','1','2']
string3=[int(num) for num in string3] # [0,1,2]
for num in string3:
   print(x.get(num))# will return the value corresponding to the key
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, simply do the same stuff, but make a loop at the end, and have a `return` in the function:

```
string = input("Please enter a name> ")
def enumerate_string(string):
    s = {}
    for i,letter in enumerate(string):
        s[i] = letter
    return s

x = enumerate_string(string)
string2 = input("enter several integers separated by a comma ")
string3 = string2.split(',')
for i in string3:
    if int(i) in x:
        print(x[int(i)])
```

Example output:

```
Please enter a name> John Doe
enter several integers separated by a comma 0,1,2
J
o
h
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you U9-Forward and Amany for your input. I decided to go with U9-Forward answer but added an extra condition in case the key(integer) entered by user is out of range.